# Convert particular numeric/int into factors in R using a colname vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called df:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                customer = c("Alice", "Bob", "Carlos", "Chuck", "Craig", "Heidi", "Judy", "Rupert", "Wendy"),
                Balance = c(100, 75, 56, 172, 450, 777, 1001, 25, 968),
                Hour = c(1, 23, 4, 5, 6, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                InDebt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                DueDay = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sun", "Sat", "Thu", "Mon", "Wed"),
                AppBooked = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
                )
```

I want to convert certain columns (in this instance Hour, InDebt, AppBooked) to factors and at present have been using the following method:

```
df$Hour <- as.factor(df$Hour)
df$InDebt <- as.factor(df$InDebt)
df$AppBooked <- as.factor(df$AppBooked)
```

Although this works, I wanted to see if there was a quicker way of doing this (particularly if I have to do it for 100 different column names).  I'm basically interested in converting a specific set of numeric variables into factors (but not all numeric variables).  I've been trying to get this to work using the lapply function and dplyr, storing my column names in a vector, however, I'm having difficulty getting it to work:

```
colsasfactors <- (c("Hour", "InDebt", "AppBooked"))

df <- df %>%
        lapply(colnames(df) %in% colsasfactor, factor)
```

Clearly, I'm missing something (my suspicion being that I'm using %in% incorrectly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can use `across()` with `mutate()` using the index position of each variable. If you have 100 variables it is easy to use index number than names:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                 customer = c("Alice", "Bob", "Carlos", "Chuck", "Craig", "Heidi", "Judy", "Rupert", "Wendy"),
                 Balance = c(100, 75, 56, 172, 450, 777, 1001, 25, 968),
                 Hour = c(1, 23, 4, 5, 6, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                 InDebt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 DueDay = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sun", "Sat", "Thu", "Mon", "Wed"),
                 AppBooked = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),stringsAsFactors = F
)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(4,5,7),factor))
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ id       : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 $ customer : chr  "Alice" "Bob" "Carlos" "Chuck" ...
 $ Balance  : num  100 75 56 172 450 ...
 $ Hour     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","4","5","6",..: 1 8 2 3 4 5 6 7 7
 $ InDebt   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2
 $ DueDay   : chr  "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Fri" ...
 $ AppBooked: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

Or using your variable vector `colsasfactors`:

```
#Code 2
df <- df %>% mutate(across(colsasfactors,factor))
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ id       : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 $ customer : chr  "Alice" "Bob" "Carlos" "Chuck" ...
 $ Balance  : num  100 75 56 172 450 ...
 $ Hour     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","4","5","6",..: 1 8 2 3 4 5 6 7 7
 $ InDebt   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2
 $ DueDay   : chr  "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Fri" ...
 $ AppBooked: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2
```

Comment: I haven't seen the across function before.  This is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mutate_at`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html):

```
df <- df %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(Hour, InDebt, AppBooked), factor)
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newer `across()` function with mutate

```
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(across( c(Hour, InDebt, AppBooked), as.factor) )
```

You can also use `mutate_at` but it has now been depreciated in `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `data.table` package to do that:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                 customer = c("Alice", "Bob", "Carlos", "Chuck", "Craig",
                              "Heidi", "Judy", "Rupert", "Wendy"),
                 Balance = c(100, 75, 56, 172, 450, 777, 1001, 25, 968),
                 Hour = c(1, 23, 4, 5, 6, 12, 14, 17, 17),
                 InDebt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 DueDay = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sun",
                            "Sat", "Thu", "Mon", "Wed"),
                 AppBooked = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))

require(data.table)
setDT(df)

cols = c("Hour", "InDebt", "AppBooked")
df[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = cols ]

sapply(df, class) # check column classes
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
df[,colsasfactors] <- lapply(df[,colsasfactors],as.factor)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  7 variables:
#   $ id       : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# $ customer : chr  "Alice" "Bob" "Carlos" "Chuck" ...
# $ Balance  : num  100 75 56 172 450 ...
# $ Hour     : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","4","5","6",..: 1 8 2 3 4 5 6 7 7
# $ InDebt   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2
# $ DueDay   : chr  "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Fri" ...
# $ AppBooked: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2
```